# Whatever happened to the Magento Community Engineering Slack?

Tags: magento2

At the M2 github page: https://github.com/magento/magento2/wiki/Slack-Channels

..there are a few links to https://opensource.magento.com that don't work:

[image: 403 forbidden]

Is that Slack community not active anymore, or is it now closed to outsiders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need a @magento.com, @divante.pl, @divante.co, @webvisum.de, or @adobe.com email address.

So on that basis not open to outsiders

I have slack app installed on phone and this link worked for me

`#adobe-stock`

https://magentocommeng.slack.com/messages/CJLSYEPFA

Screen presents info that would suggest you now need one of those email address domains above

```
Edit in response to comment
```

I just tried hotmail address and it wouldn't let me

Comment: Jus want to add , that I use Gmail account there and it's working.